# An example of PHP curl_multi_exec() without curl_multi_select()?

Tags: php, curl-multi

Does anyone have an example of using [curl_multi_exec](http://www.php.net/curl_multi_exec)() without [curl_multi_select](http://www.php.net/curl_multi_select)() ? One of our servers still uses Centos5 with PHP5.1.x.

Also the example should allow processing the handles before everyone has finished.

My implementation has problems with sites without Content-Length parameter and request body over buffer size (16k). Without the Content-Length from server the [curl_getinfo](http://www.php.net/curl_getinfo)()['download_content_length'] is always -1.

Comment: We can be of more help if you shared existing code.

Comment: One way to accomplish this is to monitor the total_time from get_info and see when it stops running for a handle. Then the request has finished.

Answer (score 0):

something like this.

```
$curlMulti = curl_multi_init();
$handles = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/request/$i");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_multi_add_handle($curlMulti, $ch);
  $handles[] = $ch;
}

do {
  $curlMultiStatus = curl_multi_exec($curlMulti, $runningHandles);

  // Process completed handles
  while ($completedHandle = curl_multi_info_read($curlMulti)) {
     $handle = $completedHandle['handle'];
     $response = curl_multi_getcontent($handle);
     $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
     echo "Handle completed: $httpCode\n";
     curl_multi_remove_handle($curlMulti, $handle);
     curl_close($handle);
  }
    
} while ($curlMultiStatus == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM || $runningHandles);

curl_multi_close($curlMulti);
```